# Shared Folder stop working after reboot

Tags: windows, network-shares

Ok i have this setup on my business :

PC1 is the server for the program we use, PC2 and PC3 use this program remotely via a shared folder in homegroup, the program needs a key that is stored in a usb flash drive that is always plugged at PC1.

PC1 and 2 are Windows 7 x64 one is Windows 8.1. If i share the folder(lets call it X), map the folder on others PC's and "start" the key on PC1 all works OK.

Now the problem is: If PC1 is rebooted by any reason, after the boot no other PC's can access the shared folder it says it can't connect to it. I've set a scheduled task to "start" the key at boot. I would expect that after PC1 completely boot, all others computers should be able to run X without any more action.

Right now I can't even map the folder again. I get the error "folder is not valid" something like this. My business works 24 hours, 7 days. I need it to back to work if PC1 is powered off by any reason. Any input please?

Edit: After reboot the Windows 8.1 machine i'm able to remap the folder again. Any help please. I need this shared folder to be persistent even if PC1 reboots for any reasons